# install g77 using fink

Tags: macos, fortran, fink

I am trying to install convex optimization package OBOE:
https://projects.coin-or.org/OBOE/wiki/MacosxOboe

I followed its instruction, but I run into errors in this step:

```
fink install g77
```

I think fink is properly install because:

```
fink install atlas
```

is run successfully;

while

```
fink install g77
```

tells me:

```
Information about 10346 packages read in 1 seconds.
Failed: no package found for specification 'g77'!
```

does someone know what happened? Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask at http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: You could try to install `gfortran` instead.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/157816/24154.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  @VladimirF, for the future, if you're going to suggest another site, please make sure to remind people not to cross-post (tell them they can delete their question and post it elsewhere, if they posted on the wrong site).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler `g77` is quite old and part of the gcc 3.x era.  Since gcc 4.0, `g77` has been replaced by `gfortran`.  While `gfortran` is not an F77 compiler, it should compile just about any standards compliant (and with some vendor extensions) F77 code.  I would advise to avoid any tutorial asking you to install compilers like `g77` or `f2c` as it is a clear sign they are severely out of date.

If fink doesn't have an easy installation of `gfortran` (and it doesn't sound like it does), consider using macports to install a Fortran compiler.  Note than with macports, the Fortran compiler is part of the gcc package, so you would use a command like:

```
sudo port install gcc48
```

to install the GNU compiler collection, including `gfortran`.

Comment: gfortran seems to be part of fink's gcc49 package (and potentially other versions, but I have gcc49 installed).

Comment: @JayFreeman-saurik- It will be part of all of the `gcc4X` packages.